# Не дорисовывает линию в dataGridView

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Господа помогите понять почему e.Graphics.DrawLine не дорисовывает линию в последней колонки dataGridView, перепробовал множество вариантов но бестолку уже день бьюсь над этим.

```
    private void dataGridView3_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
    {
        using (Brush b = new SolidBrush(dataGridView3.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor))
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(b, e.CellBounds);

        e.PaintContent(e.ClipBounds);
        if (e.RowIndex == -1)  // column header
        {
            //e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Gainsboro, 0, e.CellBounds.Bottom - 1, e.ClipBounds.Width, e.CellBounds.Bottom - 1);
            //e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Gainsboro, 0, e.CellBounds.Bottom - 1, dataGridView3.PreferredSize.Width, e.CellBounds.Bottom - 1);
            //e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Gainsboro, 0, e.CellBounds.Bottom - 1, dataGridView3.Right, e.CellBounds.Bottom - 1);
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Red, 0, e.CellBounds.Bottom - 1, e.CellBounds.Right, e.CellBounds.Bottom - 1);

        }
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: На момент прорисовки она скрыта?

Comment: Нет колонка не  скрыта, но если я  для проверки добавлю новую то уже на ней проблема а на предыдущей все прорисовывается

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте, что-то в этом роде

```
private void dataGridView1_RowPostPaint(object sender, DataGridViewRowPostPaintEventArgs e)    
{
    if (e.RowIndex == 0)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Red, e.RowBounds.Left, e.RowBounds.Top -2 , e.RowBounds.Right, e.RowBounds.Top -2);
    }
}
```